# create JSONArray from JSONObject

Tags: java, json

Good day all

I am having trouble parsing a JSONArray from a JSONObject. I might just be misunderstanding.

Creating the JSONObject to send:

```
int i = 0;
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
String line;

while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    JSONObject rule = new JSONObject().put("rule", line);
    jsonArray.put(i,rule);
    i++;
}
return (new JSONObject().put(jsonStrings.REQUEST_RULES_ALL_RESPONSE, jsonArray));
```

This send a json array within a json object, to make things simpler. This is correct.

the returned object is in this format:

```
{"REQUEST_RULES_ALL_RESPONSE":[ 
        {"rule":"something"},
        {"rule":"something"},
        {"rule":"something"}  ]}
```

I would like to parse this into a List RULES.
Reading the JSONObject recieved:

```
//this returns the object as described above
JSONObject jsonObject = serverData.SendData(new JSONObject().put(jsonStrings.REQUEST_RULES_ALL, " ")); 

//Trying to Convert to JSONArray, the get strings are correct, 
//notice the REQUEST and REQUEST RESPONSE.

//problem line below
JSONArray JSONFirewallRules = new JSONArray ((JSONArray)jsonObject.get(jsonStrings.REQUEST_RULES_ALL_RESPONSE));
```

> ERROR: org.json.JSONException: Not a primitive array: class
>   org.json.JSONArray

I do not understand why this is a problem. I would like to get the JSONArray from the object.

Comment: jsonArray.put(i,rule);  to    jsonArray.put(rule);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the problematic line, instead of casting to a JSONArray, use getJSONArray:

```
JSONArray JSONFirewallRules = jsonObject.getJSONArray(jsonStrings.REQUEST_RULES_ALL_RESPONSE);
```

However the exception isn't a cast exception, but a constructor exception where you are trying to build a JSONArray object from an unsupported list of items, which is another JSONArray :)

Answer (score 1):

`jsonObject.getJSONArray(key)` throw exception in case key not found
Use **jsonObject.opt...** methods. These methods just return null if key not found in json object
Use `jsonObject.optJSONArray(key)` instead of `jsonObject.getJSONArray(key)`